# SWIG Python C/C++. The resulting module is empty, no errors

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

## For anyone in the future

The solution is in the comments of the question and the reply.

---

I'm trying to create a python interface for the [musly](https://github.com/dominikschnitzer/musly) software (C/C++), more specifically for the libmusly, with swig. I'm using a building directory that is the /libmusly directory from the linked repo with the /include directory from the same repo inside it.

I'm using the following swig interface named lib.i, since the methods I want to access are in the lib.cpp file. I will say in advance that the section at the end makes me thing the problem is in this file.

```
/* lib.i */ 
%module libmusly 
%{ 
typedef struct {
    void* method;
    char* method_name;
    void* decoder;
    char* decoder_name; } musly_jukebox;

typedef float musly_track;

typedef int musly_trackid;

const char* musly_version();

void musly_debug(
        int level);

const char* musly_jukebox_listmethods();

const char* musly_jukebox_listdecoders();

const char* musly_jukebox_aboutmethod(
        musly_jukebox* jukebox);

musly_jukebox* musly_jukebox_poweron(
        const char* method,
        const char* decoder);   int musly_jukebox_similarity(
        musly_jukebox* jukebox,
        musly_track* seed_track,
        musly_trackid seed_trackid,
        musly_track** tracks,
        musly_trackid* trackids,
        int num_tracks,
        float* similarities);

musly_track* musly_track_alloc(
        musly_jukebox* jukebox);

void musly_track_free(
        musly_track* track);

int musly_track_size(
        musly_jukebox* jukebox);

int musly_track_analyze_audiofile(
        musly_jukebox* jukebox,
        const char* audiofile,
        float excerpt_length,
        float excerpt_start,
        musly_track* track);    
%}
```

I'm using the following file to build and link it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Generating swig wrapper file." 
swig3.0 -c++ -python lib.i

echo "Compiling." 
c++ -fPIC -c -lstdc++ -DNDEBUG -Dlibmusly_EXPORTS
-DHAVE_AVUTIL_CHANNEL_LAYOUT -DMUSLY_VERSION=\"0.2\" -I./ -I./include/ -I./libresample/ -I./decoders/ -I./kissfft/ -I./methods/ -I/usr/include/python3.5m/ -I/usr/include/eigen3/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu lib_wrap.cxx kissfft/kiss_fft.c kissfft/kiss_fftr.c methods/mandelellis.cpp methods/timbre.cpp decoders/libav.cpp resampler.cpp plugins.cpp method.cpp decoder.cpp windowfunction.cpp powerspectrum.cpp melspectrum.cpp discretecosinetransform.cpp mfcc.cpp gaussianstatistics.cpp mutualproximity.cpp lib.cpp

c++ -fPIC -c -lstdc++ -DNDEBUG -Dlibmusly_EXPORTS
-DHAVE_AVUTIL_CHANNEL_LAYOUT -DMUSLY_VERSION=\"0.2\" -I./ -I./include/ -I./libresample/ -I./decoders/ -I./kissfft/ -I./methods/ -I/usr/include/python3.5m/ -I/usr/include/eigen3/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu libresample/filterkit.c libresample/resamplesubs.c libresample/resample.c 

echo "Linking." 
cc  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libmusly_resample.so
-o libmusly_resample.so libresample/filterkit.o libresample/resamplesubs.o libresample/resample.o 

c++ -fPIC  -shared -Wl,-soname,_libmusly.so -o _libmusly.so kiss_fft.o kiss_fftr.o mandelellis.o timbre.o libav.o resampler.o plugins.o method.o decoder.o windowfunction.o powerspectrum.o melspectrum.o discretecosinetransform.o mfcc.o gaussianstatistics.o mutualproximity.o libmusly_resample.so lib.o lib_wrap.o -lavcodec
-lavformat -lavutil -lpython3.5m
```

The mentioned in the title I can import the resulting module into the python interpreter I linked against, 3.5m, with no errors. But the module simply has no methods besides the standard ones, that being and end with an "_" (underscore), and a few swig related methods that also begin and end with an underscore.

I did try importing libmusly and _libmusly, the former always contains the later anyways. The methods within them are different but the same problem exists, none of my methods are there.

The files in the directory after compilation are:

```
./:
build.sh
decoder.cpp
decoder.h
decoder.o
decoders
discretecosinetransform.cpp
discretecosinetransform.h
discretecosinetransform.o
files.txt
filterkit.o
gaussian.h
gaussianstatistics.cpp
gaussianstatistics.h
gaussianstatistics.o
idpool.h
include
kissfft
kiss_fft.o
kiss_fftr.o
libav.o
lib.cpp
lib.i
libmusly.py
libmusly_resample.so
_libmusly.so
lib.o
libresample
lib_wrap.cxx
lib_wrap.o
mandelellis.o
melspectrum.cpp
melspectrum.h
melspectrum.o
method.cpp
method.h
method.o
methods
mfcc.cpp
mfcc.h
mfcc.o
mutualproximity.cpp
mutualproximity.h
mutualproximity.o
plugins.cpp
plugins.h
plugins.o
powerspectrum.cpp
powerspectrum.h
powerspectrum.o
resample.o
resampler.cpp
resampler.h
resampler.o
resamplesubs.o
timbre.o
windowfunction.cpp
windowfunction.h
windowfunction.o

./decoders:
libav.cpp
libav.h

./include:
CMakeLists.txt
minilog.h
minilog.h.gch
musly

./include/musly:
musly.h
musly.h.gch
musly_types.h

./kissfft:
CHANGELOG
COPYING
kiss_fft.c
_kiss_fft_guts.h
kiss_fft.h
kiss_fftr.c
kiss_fftr.h
README
README.simd
TIPS

./libresample:
CMakeLists.txt
filterkit.c
filterkit.h
filterkit.o
libresample.h
LICENSE.txt
README.txt
resample.c
resample_defs.h
resample.o
resamplesubs.c
resamplesubs.o

./methods:
mandelellis.cpp
mandelellis.h
timbre.cpp
timbre.h
```

The contents of libmusly.py are:

```
# This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
# Version 3.0.10
#
# Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
# the SWIG interface file instead.





from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info
if _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 7, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_libmusly')).lstrip('.')
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
        except ImportError:
            return importlib.import_module('_libmusly')
    _libmusly = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
elif _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_libmusly', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _libmusly
            return _libmusly
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.load_module('_libmusly', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _libmusly = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _libmusly
del _swig_python_version_info
try:
    _swig_property = property
except NameError:
    pass  # Python < 2.2 doesn't have 'property'.

try:
    import builtins as __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__

def _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, static=1):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own(value)
    if (name == "this"):
        if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            return
    method = class_type.__swig_setmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self, value)
    if (not static):
        if _newclass:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
    else:
        raise AttributeError("You cannot add attributes to %s" % self)


def _swig_setattr(self, class_type, name, value):
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, 0)


def _swig_getattr(self, class_type, name):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own()
    method = class_type.__swig_getmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self)
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))


def _swig_repr(self):
    try:
        strthis = "proxy of " + self.this.__repr__()
    except __builtin__.Exception:
        strthis = ""
    return "<%s.%s; %s >" % (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__, strthis,)

try:
    _object = object
    _newclass = 1
except __builtin__.Exception:
    class _object:
        pass
    _newclass = 0

# This file is compatible with both classic and new-style classes.
```

I'm using Debian 9 on an Intel i3 from ~2013, everything was installed from the repos. Swig is version 3 and c++ 6.3.0. The swig docs recommend c++ for compiling c++ but I did try other compilers and got the same result.

---

When I try to add the following code to the end of /libmusly/CMakeLists.txt and compiling I get two files "libmusly.py" and "_libmusly.so", the former I have to rename to "_libmusly.py" only to get the same problem. But the resulting _libmusly.so is much bigger than the one I get through the other method, 14,6MB vs 3,5MB.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED) INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs) INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBMUSLY_INCLUDE}    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}   ${LIBAV_INCLUDE_DIRS}   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}     ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON) SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall") SWIG_ADD_MODULE(libmusly python lib.i
    kissfft/kiss_fft.c
    kissfft/kiss_fftr.c
    methods/mandelellis.cpp
    methods/timbre.cpp
    decoders/libav.cpp
    resampler.cpp
    plugins.cpp
    method.cpp
    decoder.cpp
    windowfunction.cpp
    powerspectrum.cpp
    melspectrum.cpp
    discretecosinetransform.cpp
    mfcc.cpp
    gaussianstatistics.cpp
    mutualproximity.cpp
    lib.cpp) SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(libmusly
    ${LIBMUSLY_LIBS}
    ${LIBAV_LIBRARIES}
    ${LIBMUSLY_EXTERNAL}
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

---

## Update after Mark's reply

I can't import the resulting module anymore after using `%inline` before the `%{ %}` block. The interpreter complains about an undefined symbol even though it is defined in the .i and .cpp files. I think it might be a linking error but I don't know what. The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tuco/Desenvolvimento/libmusly_swig/libmusly.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /home/tuco/Desenvolvimento/libmusly_swig/_libmusly.so: undefined symbol: _Z26musly_jukebox_listdecodersv

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tuco/Desenvolvimento/libmusly_swig/libmusly.py", line 21, in <module>
    _libmusly = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/tuco/Desenvolvimento/libmusly_swig/libmusly.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_libmusly')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: /home/tuco/Desenvolvimento/libmusly_swig/_libmusly.so: undefined symbol: _Z26musly_jukebox_listdecodersv
```

New libmusly.py

```
# This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
# Version 3.0.10
#
# Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
# the SWIG interface file instead.





from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info
if _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 7, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_libmusly')).lstrip('.')
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
        except ImportError:
            return importlib.import_module('_libmusly')
    _libmusly = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
elif _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_libmusly', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _libmusly
            return _libmusly
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.load_module('_libmusly', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _libmusly = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _libmusly
del _swig_python_version_info
try:
    _swig_property = property
except NameError:
    pass  # Python < 2.2 doesn't have 'property'.

try:
    import builtins as __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__

def _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, static=1):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own(value)
    if (name == "this"):
        if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            return
    method = class_type.__swig_setmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self, value)
    if (not static):
        if _newclass:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
    else:
        raise AttributeError("You cannot add attributes to %s" % self)


def _swig_setattr(self, class_type, name, value):
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, 0)


def _swig_getattr(self, class_type, name):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own()
    method = class_type.__swig_getmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self)
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))


def _swig_repr(self):
    try:
        strthis = "proxy of " + self.this.__repr__()
    except __builtin__.Exception:
        strthis = ""
    return "<%s.%s; %s >" % (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__, strthis,)

try:
    _object = object
    _newclass = 1
except __builtin__.Exception:
    class _object:
        pass
    _newclass = 0

class musly_jukebox(_object):
    __swig_setmethods__ = {}
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, musly_jukebox, name, value)
    __swig_getmethods__ = {}
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, musly_jukebox, name)
    __repr__ = _swig_repr
    __swig_setmethods__["method"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_set
    __swig_getmethods__["method"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_get
    if _newclass:
        method = _swig_property(_libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_get, _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_set)
    __swig_setmethods__["method_name"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_name_set
    __swig_getmethods__["method_name"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_name_get
    if _newclass:
        method_name = _swig_property(_libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_name_get, _libmusly.musly_jukebox_method_name_set)
    __swig_setmethods__["decoder"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_set
    __swig_getmethods__["decoder"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_get
    if _newclass:
        decoder = _swig_property(_libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_get, _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_set)
    __swig_setmethods__["decoder_name"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_name_set
    __swig_getmethods__["decoder_name"] = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_name_get
    if _newclass:
        decoder_name = _swig_property(_libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_name_get, _libmusly.musly_jukebox_decoder_name_set)

    def __init__(self):
        this = _libmusly.new_musly_jukebox()
        try:
            self.this.append(this)
        except __builtin__.Exception:
            self.this = this
    __swig_destroy__ = _libmusly.delete_musly_jukebox
    __del__ = lambda self: None
musly_jukebox_swigregister = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_swigregister
musly_jukebox_swigregister(musly_jukebox)


def musly_version():
    return _libmusly.musly_version()
musly_version = _libmusly.musly_version

def musly_debug(level):
    return _libmusly.musly_debug(level)
musly_debug = _libmusly.musly_debug

def musly_jukebox_listmethods():
    return _libmusly.musly_jukebox_listmethods()
musly_jukebox_listmethods = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_listmethods

#def musly_jukebox_listdecoders():
#    return _libmusly.musly_jukebox_listdecoders()
#musly_jukebox_listdecoders = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_listdecoders

def musly_jukebox_aboutmethod(jukebox):
    return _libmusly.musly_jukebox_aboutmethod(jukebox)
musly_jukebox_aboutmethod = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_aboutmethod

def musly_jukebox_poweron(method, decoder):
    return _libmusly.musly_jukebox_poweron(method, decoder)
musly_jukebox_poweron = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_poweron

def musly_jukebox_similarity(jukebox, seed_track, seed_trackid, tracks, trackids, num_tracks, similarities):
    return _libmusly.musly_jukebox_similarity(jukebox, seed_track, seed_trackid, tracks, trackids, num_tracks, similarities)
musly_jukebox_similarity = _libmusly.musly_jukebox_similarity

def musly_track_alloc(jukebox):
    return _libmusly.musly_track_alloc(jukebox)
musly_track_alloc = _libmusly.musly_track_alloc

def musly_track_free(track):
    return _libmusly.musly_track_free(track)
musly_track_free = _libmusly.musly_track_free

def musly_track_size(jukebox):
    return _libmusly.musly_track_size(jukebox)
musly_track_size = _libmusly.musly_track_size

def musly_track_analyze_audiofile(jukebox, audiofile, excerpt_length, excerpt_start, track):
    return _libmusly.musly_track_analyze_audiofile(jukebox, audiofile, excerpt_length, excerpt_start, track)
musly_track_analyze_audiofile = _libmusly.musly_track_analyze_audiofile
# This file is compatible with both classic and new-style classes.
```

Comment: Start with the simplest working C code to call a function in the library.  Any header files you #include to make it work should be in the `%{ %}` section so the wrapper includes them, too.  Then add one declaration from the header of a function you want to call after the `%{ %}` section and see if you can build a wrapper with SWIG and call that function from Python.  Share the .i file and your build steps if you have trouble.

Comment: It worked.  I included the `#includes` from lib.cpp on lib.i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.i` file, code between `%{` and `%}` is directly included in the wrapper with no modification.  Code at the module level is parsed by SWIG and wrapper functions are created.  For example:

```
%module test

%{
int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }  // declares a function that will appear in test_wrap.c
%}

int func(int a, int b);  // SWIG creates a wrapper function in test_wrap.c
```

You can also do `%inline %{ %}` which both declares and creates wrappers:

```
%module test

%inline %{
int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
%}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now get an error, I updated my original question and included it at the bottom.

Comment: @tuco94 Your error is because you didn't link the Python extension that was generated against the actual implementation of your functions.

Comment: Didn't I? I linked lib.o(where the function is) and lib_wrap.o against _libmusly.so. Isn't that it? (The last line in the second code snippet in my question)